# How can I create a sinusoidal path for a moving object in 2D where points on the sine wave are dictated by measurement time and object's speed

Tags: matlab

I need to simulate a 2D object in MATLAB that is moving in a sinusoidal fashion from some point A (x1,y1) to some other point B (x2,y2).

The object's position is measured discretely every time delta: dT.

The object's speed is a constant: v.

given the above two parameters, I expect each line segment between points to have length = v * dT.

As an example, Let's say I want my object to travel from point A to point B with sinusoidal motion, and the object is moving 2m/s and I take a measurement once per second, I would expect each line segment between measurements to be 2m long, and I do not know how to determine the total length the curve would be.

I have no clue how to begin implementing this.

For a visual, I've provided a plot of what I expect. The green line is the path the object should be following, the blue dots are measurements.
[Example Plot of Tracked Object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UoABz.png)

Comment: Do you need determine the length from the measurements or from properties of the sinusoid (amplitude, wavelength) if they are known?

Comment: The 2m/s example, is this the speed along the straight line between A and B, or is it the speed along the sine wave arc ?

Comment: @Hoki linear speed along sine wave arc.

Comment: @JAC I suppose from the sinusoid's properties. At the end of the day I want to know where to place measurement points along the sinusoid such that they indicate the object has moved at a particular speed along the sine wave.

Comment: Then to get the _ total length the curve_ you also need to define/know: (i) the distance between A and B, (ii) the linear speed between A and B, (iii) the amplitude of the sine, (iv) the frequency (or period) of the sine wave. These 4 parameters will allow you to calculate everything else you're asking. You need to work out the equations though, and come back here to get help to code it. At the moment, we cannot create a model for you when half the inputs are unknown.